# Deserializing XML object array using XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

Currently I'm working on some code that deserializes a XML file into an object. I have figured out most of the Attributes that I have to use to make this work except for one case, described below.

This is the XML document that I'm trying to Deserialize.

The pages-element is an array.
The page-element is an object.
The object-elements in the page are supposed to be in an array but they aren't when you take a look at the XML format. The amount of objects is variable though.

```
<document>
    <pages>
        <page>
            <object></object>
            <object></object>
            <object></object>
        </page>
        <page>
            <object></object>
        </page>
        <page>
            <object></object>
            <object></object>
        </page>
    </pages>
</document>
```

These are the classes that form the object that I'm trying to deserialize it to.

```
[XmlRoot("document")]
public class Document
{
    [XmlArrayItem("page", typeof(Page))]
    [XmlArray("pages")]
    public Page[] pages;
}

[XmlRoot("page")]
public class Page
{
    public Object[] objects;
}

[XmlRoot("object")]
public class Object
{

}
```

The question then is; what attributes do I need to enable the XmlSerializer class to deserialize the XML to a Document object?

Comment: Your page array has two xml tags 1) Pages 2) Page.  The object array has only one xml tag.  So you need to add [XmlElement("object")].  The default for serialization for an array is two xml tags.

Comment: @jdweng Well that was quick. I added [XmlElement("object"] to the array objects in the Page class and that seems to work. Thanks